# Symfony2: How to embed embed collection for pre-determined amount of collection items?

Tags: symfony

Working on a simple job application app that lets users specify multiple references on the application form. I have an `Application` entity and `Reference` entity. There is a `OneToMany` association from Application -> Reference and a `ManyToOne` association from Reference -> Listing.

Snippet from my `Application` form class:

```
    $builder
        ...
        ->add('references', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new ReferenceType(),
            'allow_add' => false,
            'allow_delete' => false,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'delete_empty' => true,
            'empty_data' => null,
        ))
        ...
    ;
```

When rendering the application form, I want to present 5 embedded reference forms (the user can submit a maximum of 5 references). I do not want buttons to dynamically add or remove references (one reason is I want this form to work w/o javascript).

To do this, I've done this in the controller:

```
    ...
    $application = new Application();
    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
        $reference = new Reference();
        $application->addReference($reference);
    }
    ...
```

Then I create the application form and pass in the application object.

The problem is if the user leaves some blank, I don't want to consider them at all. When I bind the form to the request, I need the form component to somehow remove the `Reference` items that are empty from the collection.

I can't seem to achieve this. I was trying all sorts of different options for the `collection` field type, but nothing works. After I bind the request to the form, the `Application` entity still has a collection of 5 `References`, even if many have all null values.